# calculate the sum of the muplication of 2 columns in org table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have a org table:

```
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | i |
| 3 | 4 | j |
|---+---+---|
| 4 | 6 |   |
```

I want to multiply columns `a` and `b` and sum them up (except last row: `1*2+3*4`) and put into the last cell:

```
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | i |
| 3 | 4 | j |
|---+---+---|
| 4 | 6 | 14|
```

What is the formula to achieve this? I tried `#+TBLFM: @>$>=sum($1 * $2)` without luck.

My org version: Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/org/)

Comment: This is the *scalar product* of two vectors. Emacs calc (which is used by the table code in Org mode) can calculate the scalar product of two vectors using `*`, so the trick is to figure out how to specify the two vectors. @gigiair's answer shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 @4$3=(@2$1..@3$1)*(@2$2..@3$2)
```

or

```
 @>$>=(@<<$<..@>>$<)*(@<<$<<..@>>$<<)
```

or

```
 @>$>=(@I$1..@II$1)*(@I$2..@II$2)
```

using the horizontal lines to delimit instead of explicit row numbers.

The [relevant section of the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References) is dense but well-worth reading (and re-reading).

Comment: parentheses are not mandatory, but make the formula easyer to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Orgtbl-Aggregate` package available on Melpa

The sums are in a separate table, easy to update

```
#+name: mytable
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | i |
| 3 | 4 | j |

#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "mytable" :cols "vsum(a) vsum(b) vsum(a*b)"
| vsum(a) | vsum(b) | vsum(a*b) |
|---------+---------+-----------|
|       4 |       6 |        14 |
#+END:
```